# Simplify dplyr code in R for selecting minimum value in a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, tidyverse, min

I need to print the first 3 months having the min price of **Premium** product in a product dataset:

```
   Date          Grade   Price
   <chr>         <ord>    <dbl>
 1 January 2016  Regular   22.20
 2 January 2016  Premium   32.45
 3 January 2016  Premium   55.34
 4 February 2016 Regular   23.69
 ... with 100 more rows
```

The result will look like this:

```
      Date          Price
      <chr>         <dbl>
1 March 2017         21.13
2 May 2017           21.35
3 October 2017       21.67
```

Using dplyr, I have the following codes, but it seems a bit long. Is there any way to simplify this?

```
min <- select(product, Date, Price)
min <- filter(min, Grade == "Premium")
min <- arrange(min, Price)
min[1:3,]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to avoid the repeated assignment, use a chain (`%>%`).  It seems that these steps are unique steps that may not be possible to simplify in `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 product %>%
      select(Date, Price)  %>%
      filter(Grade == 'Premium') %>%
      arrange(Price) %>%
      slice_head(3)
```

---

In `base R`, we may simplify this

```
out <- subset(product, select = c(Date, Price), subset = Grade == 'Premium')
head(out[order(out$Price),], 3)
```